# 360 VR production using WebGL of unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

360 VR production using WebGL of unity3d

I am working on 360 VR through unity3d WebGL.

When running on the mobile Web, I want to see 360 VR using Gyro.

So I made GyroControl and it worked during Android Building.
But it doesn't work on WebGL.

```c#
void Start()
{
    cameraContainer = new GameObject("Camera Container");
    cameraContainer.transform.position = transform.position;
    transform.SetParent(cameraContainer.transform);

    gyroEnabled = EnableGyro();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(gyroEnabled)
    {
        transform.localRotation = gyro.attitude * rot;
    }
}

private bool EnableGyro()
{
    if(SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope)
    {
        gyro = Input.gyro;
        gyro.enabled = true;

        cameraContainer.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90f, 90f, 0);
        rot = new Quaternion(0, 0, 1, 0);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Let me know if there's any way.

Comment: well afaik [`Gyroscope`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope.html) only works for `iOS` and `Android` .. so on WebGL I guess `SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope` will be `false`. You could maybe try to interact with a [JavaScript code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) for getting the gyro data ...

Comment: If you want to use giro in WebGL, you need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As you may have noticed, most of the Unity API by Default related to sensors & modules does not work on WebGL platform. But there are Unity Assets and Plugins which fix this issue. Post contains affiliate links.

- [Gyroscope Accelerometer WebGL](https://makaka.org/o/webgl-sensors) — enables you to read the gyroscope and accelerometer information provided by browser.
- [Geolocation WebGL](https://makaka.org/o/webgl-gps) — allows you to access GPS on the web.
- [Device Camera WebGL](https://makaka.org/o/webgl-camera) - allows you to access the camera feed and stream its contents into a render texture (or Texture2D). It works on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, Edge.
- [Vibration WebGL](https://makaka.org/o/webgl-vibration) - enables you to vibrate your mobile phone. You can control how long you want to keep the mobile vibrating, as well as define a vibration sequence.
- [Screen Orientation WebGL](https://makaka.org/o/webgl-orientation) — a way to listen to device orientation changes.